# Multiline table header

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable

Is it possible typeset a table with `\pgfplotstabletypeset` and change the style of 1 column header to be multiline?

This code doesn't work and can't compile:

```
...
columns/errorRelC/.style={
    column name=Line 1\\Line 2
},
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy way to obtain this is by using the [`makecell` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell). It provides `\makecell[<alignment>]{<tabular stuff>}` that you can use to typeset this kind of line-breaking stuff.

```
\usepackage{makecell}% http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell
%...
columns/errorRelC/.style={
    column name=\makecell{Line 1\\Line 2}
},
%...
```

Here is a complete minimal example from the [`pgfplotstable` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplotstable.pdf):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable
\usepackage{makecell}% http://ctan.org/pkg/makecell
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableset{% global config, for example in the preamble
                  % these columns/<colname>/.style={<options>} things define a style
                  % which applies to <colname> only.
  columns/dof/.style={int detect,column type=r,column name=\makecell[t]{\textsc{Dof}\\Line 2}},
  columns/error1/.style={
    sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,precision=1,sci superscript,
    column name=$e_1$,
  },
  columns/error2/.style={
    sci,sci zerofill,sci sep align,precision=2,sci 10e,
    column name=$e_2$,
  },
  columns/{grad(log(dof),log(error2))}/.style={
    string replace={0}{}, % erase '0'
    column name={$\nabla e_2$},
    dec sep align,
  },
  columns/{quot(error1)}/.style={
    string replace={0}{}, % erase '0'
    column name={$\frac{e_1^{(n)}}{e_1^{(n-1)}}$}
  },
  empty cells with={--}, % replace empty cells with '--'
  every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
  }
  \pgfplotstabletypeset[ % local config, applies only for this table
    1000 sep={\,},
    columns/info/.style={
      fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=1,showpos,
      column type=r,
    }
  ]
{
  %# Convergence results
  %# fictional source, generated 2008
  level  dof         error1         error2 info grad(log(dof),log(error2)) quot(error1)
  1        4 2.50000000e-01 7.57858283e-01 48  0              0
  2       16 6.25000000e-02 5.00000000e-01 25 -3.00000000e-01 4
  3       64 1.56250000e-02 2.87174589e-01 41 -3.99999999e-01 4
  4      256 3.90625000e-03 1.43587294e-01  8 -5.00000003e-01 4
  5     1024 9.76562500e-04 4.41941738e-02 22 -8.49999999e-01 4
  6     4096 2.44140625e-04 1.69802322e-02 46 -6.90000001e-01 4
  7    16384 6.10351562e-05 8.20091159e-03 40 -5.24999999e-01 4
  8    65536 1.52587891e-05 3.90625000e-03 48 -5.35000000e-01 3.99999999e+00
  9   262144 3.81469727e-06 1.95312500e-03 33 -5.00000000e-01 4.00000001e+00
  10 1048576 9.53674316e-07 9.76562500e-04  2 -5.00000000e-01 4.00000001e+00
}
\end{document}
```

I've used a `t`op alignment in `\makecell` for the second column header to make the first rows of each header be vertically aligned. You can specify other alignment formats, including a different horizontal alignment. See the [`makecell` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/makecell/makecell.pdf) for more information.

Alternatively, you could just write the header in a `tabular` yourself - just like `\makecell` does:

```
\pgfplotstableset{% global config, for example in the preamble
                  % these columns/<colname>/.style={<options>} things define a style
                  % which applies to <colname> only.
  columns/dof/.style={int detect,column type=r,column name=\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}\textsc{Dof}\\Line2\end{tabular}},
%...
```

Finally, you could box the content, which you then use as the `column name`. Here is how you would obtain an equivalent layout to the MWE above:

```
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}\textsc{Dof}\\Line2\end{tabular}}%

\pgfplotstableset{% global config, for example in the preamble
                  % these columns/<colname>/.style={<options>} things define a style
                  % which applies to <colname> only.
  columns/dof/.style={int detect,column type=r,column name=\usebox{\mybox}},
%...
```

The reason for all this required trickery is because the contents is inserted as-is into the table. As such, inserting `\\` in the middle somewhere would terminate the row and start a new row. Therefore, you have to "contain" it to that particular cell. Using `makecell` allows you to do the header specification within the table and allows for more freedom if changes are required and is a clean (from a code-perspective). Inserting a `tabular` is a little less clean, but works just as well, while boxing is usually done "outside" of the table and used "inside" - a little more cumbersome.

In all cases, the horizontal cell padding introduced by `tabular` (in `makecell` as well) has been removed using `@{}..@{}`.